# How to determine the last successful layer in failing docker builds

Tags: docker

When a build failed in a previous version of Docker, I could count on output like this:

```
 ---> 8f9941c285e2
Removing intermediate container 9a543227b6b8
Step 6/21 : RUN adduser -s /bin/sh -h /home/user -D user  && mkdir -p /whl  && chown -R user:user /srv /whl
 ---> Running in 93a90935664d
 ---> 7f700d063b68
Removing intermediate container 93a90935664d
```

If the step failed, the intermediate image `7f700d063b68` would still exist. I could `docker run` it and try to figure out what happened.

But now, using docker client 20.10.2 I only get this output:

```
 => [dev 1/3] COPY --from=build /whl /whl
    .1s
 => [dev 2/3] COPY --chown=user:user . .
    .9s
 => ERROR [dev 3/3] RUN python3 -m pip install --find-links /whl -e ".[bpython,test]" && command -v bpython
    .3s
```

I don't see anything in the `docker build --help` output that would seem to provide more debuggability here. `docker build` doesn't accept `--debug` or `--verbose` flags.

How can I discover what the last successful image/layer was, so I can enter it and debug with context?

Comment: It looks like the new build command (BuildKit) does not have the feature you're thinking of. You can convince the `build` command to print intermediate image hashes with `--progress=plain`, but those are not saved and can not be used with `docker run`; see also   https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1472

Comment: Is there any alternative approach I can use to debug problematic builds? For example, can I tell Docker not to use buildkit for a given build? Or, can I tell buildkit to stop building right before the failing step, without manually modifying the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think you are using BuildKit, if the variable `DOCKER_VARIABLE` is `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`? then you are using the Buildkit.

To use what was used previously to view the output of a build, then set,

`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build -t sometag .`

The BuildKit offers many improvements compared to the previous builder.

More information on the docker documentation,

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/

Comment: +1 Disabling buildkit does solve my immediate problem. But for this Q&A to be useful for a long time, and for folks who may be using buildkit-specific features, I'll wait a bit before clicking the green checkmark, in the hopes that someone has an alternative approach.

Answer (score 5):

For those like me using Buildkit, it apparently doesn't write out every intermediate image anymore.

To debug a failing step, the recommended method is to:

1. Comment out all the steps after the last successful one in the Dockerfile
2. Build an image (it will reuse the cache and just write out the finished image)
3. Run a container on the image you just generated and debug as needed